# Need Git Help: Commit & Push to remote deletes changes on remote without notification

Tags: git, github

Following situation:

Dev A commits a change in a file A and pushes the change to remote.

One month later, DEV B locally modifies file A in another part of the file, commits and pushes to remote.

PROBLEM: File A does not have the change from DEV A anymore. The file was overwritten without any notification with the version of DEV B.

On github, in the commit of DEV B, there is absolutely no diff to see in file A in the respective area where DEV A made his changes. It looks like the feature branch never contained the change from DEV A.

Question: Even when Dev B forgot to PULL before developing on file A, shouldn't he get a conflict when he wants to commit or push file A to remote?

What was going on here in general, can anyone explain that in simple words?

Here is a *gitk --all* of the situation:

[image]

Change #1 from DEV A was "Event Image Upload for Vendor"

Change #2 from DEV B is marked blue "adminbookings..."

EDIT: Next weird thing is: On github in the history of the file, I do not see the second commit, only the first:

[image]

**EDIT #2 Issue solved!** In the meantime we solved the issue. It was just a pure simple mistake on my side: I compared the wrong location within the file. In my local source I saw an INSERT statement and mistakenly thought it misses something, whereas I only implemented the missing part in the UPDATE statement which is correctly still in the source. So no error in git, just stupidity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not really. Git does what it is supposed to do under normal circumstances: it will tell you to merge stuff if you are missing stuff that it has on a branch... *but* if the user decides to force-push, then git does `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`. That is what probably happened in this case. You could set up the branch to **not** allow force-pushing, I think that is a feature on most (if not all) providers. Certainly it is a feature in github.

Comment: Many thanks. In the meantime we solved the issue. It was just a pure simple mistake on my side: I compared the wrong location within the file. In my local source I saw an INSERT statement and mistakenly thought it misses something, whereas I only implemented the missing part in the UPDATE statement which is correctly still in the source. So no error in git, just stupidity.Anyway, for your useful and important input related to the topic I will mark your Answer as accepted :)